# I'm getting an UnassignedReferenceException when the reference is set. I've seen other questions similar but not exactly the same

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the title says i'm getting the UnassignedReferenceException error for a variable already set. Using ScriptableObjects im working on an inventory system(partially from scratch) and im trying to access the EquipmentUi in another class using a GameObject to hold the prefab containing the Character script. There is no issue with this working to access the Character script as shown in the picture because i can access the name. However, when i try and access the EquipmentUI of that character it gives the error. This isnt the last part i need access to but i have figured out that the UI is the part i cant access, i need the script held in it(which has worked before in another class).

The variable is already assigned, there is no other object in my scene with the same script attached, and the code can access other parts of the script i want access to which is why i made a new post after seeing the other posts and not seeing one that had quite the same issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnitEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Character Equipment", menuName = "Inventory/Character/CharacterEquipment)]
public class CharacterEquipmentObject : ScriptableObject
{
[SerializeField]
protected Player user;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject equipmentUser; // Only used to get the user because SOs cant getObject<>
[SerializeField]
public EquipmentObject[] equipment = new EquipmentObject[8];
[SerializeField]
EquipmentDisplay equipmentUI;
//private string[] SlotList = new string[8]{"Helmet", "Shoulders", "Chest", "MainHand", "OffHand", "Ring", "Legs", "Feet"}; may need later
public void start() // must be called in display
{
    user = equipmentUser.GetComponent<Player>(); // set the user to be used in other classes\
    Debug.Log("user in CEO: " + user.characterName); // this displays fine
    Debug.Log("user " + user.characterName + "'s equipment: " + user.EquipmentUI.name); // This is what the editor says is empty when the slot has it assigned
    equipmentUI = user.EquipmentUI.GetComponentInChildren<EquipmentDisplay>();
    Debug.Log("equipmentUI: " + equipmentUI.name);
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Player class:

```
public class Player : Character
{
    [SerializeField]
    protected Character[] companions = new Character[3];
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject InventoryUI;
    public GameObject EquipmentUI;
    bool isSelling = false;
    public string characterName;

    protected override void Start() 
    {
        InventoryUI.SetActive(false);
        EquipmentUI.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("Player Equipment UI: " + EquipmentUI.GetComponentInChildren<EquipmentDisplay>().name);
        base.Start();
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        var item = other.GetComponent<InteractItem>();
        if(item)
        {
            characterInventory.addItem(item._item, 1);
            useItem(item._item);
        }    
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }


 private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            InventoryUI.SetActive(!InventoryUI.activeSelf);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            EquipmentUI.SetActive(!EquipmentUI.activeSelf);
            if(EquipmentUI.activeSelf == true)
            {
                EquipmentUI.GetComponentInChildren<EquipmentDisplay>().updateEquipmentSlots();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for Player as well? Anything to do with the EquipmentUI variable is important

Comment: Yeah ill post it in just a second on an edit.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't by accident drop this component on another object in your scene as well? Try putting `Debug.LogError("Hello!", this);` at the first line of `Start`, make sure in your console you disable `Collapse` and see how often this gets logged. Additionally you can click on the message(s) once and it will highlight according object(s).

Comment: Yes, I commented out that portion causing the stop and added the debug you mentioned and it only popped up once. When i clicked it it brought me to the proper game object and everything

Comment: I notice that Player extends Character. Does Character also contain an EquipmentUI and/or could the Start function of Character do anything to EquipmentUI?

Comment: It has one but it doesnt do anything with it yet. I want to get it working on just the one character for now so all i have for it is the getEquipment function in it

Comment: Is the EquipmentUI still attached to the PlayerPrefab gameObject in the scene when you hit the error while the game is running or does it become null/empty?

Comment: Its still there when its paused from the error. I think it may be some issue with ScriptableObjects or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help on here but i figured out it is a ScriptableObjects issue as i went in and changed the way it is run, even putting the function to edit the users InventoryObject into the player itself it still gave the same issue.

In the player function Update() that does not have the InventoryObject(ScriptableObject) the update runs fine but as soon as the player function EmptySlot() is called from the InventoryObject it sends the same error.

Not entirely sure why this is but SOs are unable to access the GameObject that holds the script for the inventory display in them whatsoever. If anyone has a reason as to why this is I would love to know, but i am going to move on from this particular part and change how it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You might be experiencing a bug I have been facing where the element variable info does not update to show variable changes.
To force it to update, cause an error in your code. Switch to unity, when it shows you the error go back and fix it, and see if the variable value changes then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sadly looks like no dice

Comment: Clicking on the error should show you on which line it is. That should make it easier to debug

Comment: I just meant it didn't work, sorry probably shouldn't have put no dice.